# Can insertion in dictionary cause KeyError?

Tags: python, exception, keyerror

Can this code ever produce KeyError? I'm new to python, just want some clarification as I checked insertion can't cause KeyError Exception.

```
def add(self, name, company):
    try:
        self.identity[self.id] = { 'name': name,
                                   'company': company }
        return self.identity
    except KeyError:
        raise NameNotAdded
```

Here **identity** is a Dictionary and **id** is an int initialized somewhere else and **NameNotAdded** is a custom exception.

Comment: No. A `KeyError` can only occur on lookup, not assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion will never raise a `KeyError`, but it can raise `TypeError` if you supply a bad key, and that generally means you're trying to use a mutable object as a key. Python integers are immutable, so they won't raise a `TypeError`.

Note that if you try to add too many items to your `dict` you will get a `MemoryError` due to lack of available RAM, or an `OverflowError` because you've attempted to exceed the maximum size of a collection (which can be read from `sys.maxsize`). But there's not much point bothering to catch those. :)

Comment: A bad key wouldn't cause a KeyError; it would be a TypeError.

Answer (score 3):

There is no any reason in that case to throw exception about [**`KeyError`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError).

A `KeyError` generally means the key doesn't exist. In your case you just adds a new key to your dictionary.